# Pasting special symbols to LaTeX file

Tags: symbols

I'm working currently on document that use many strange symbols (result of encryption). I need to print them somehow to PDF file without spending too much effort. Is there any package for this?

```
!Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:�\expandafter not set up for use wit
h LaTeX.
```

And this is text that I'm trying to print:

> ```
> Z‰~xŹz€B…z‰~xŹz€A5xŹz‡Ś„Ž5‰„~xŹz€A"V5v5‰Ž‚5‰„~xŹ€Š5… zx~„Ž5€„ŹŽxŹz€A"l5€„ŹŽxŹ€Š5vwČŠŹ€„A5Ś5vwČŠŹ€Š5‡„wvxŹz€A"V5v5‰Ž‚5‡„wvxŹ€Š5Ź~z„Ž5€‌​Šw‡vxŹz€C
> ```

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{polski} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{lstlisting} 
Z‰~xŹz€B…z‰~xŹz€A5xŹz‡Ś„Ž5‰„~xŹz€A"V5v5‰Ž‚5‰„~xŹ€Š5… zx~„Ž5€„ŹŽxŹz€A"l5€„ŹŽxŹ€Š5vwČŠŹ€„A5Ś5vwČŠŹ€Š5‡„wvxŹz€A"V5v5‰Ž‚5‡„wvxŹ€Š5Ź~z„Ž5€‌​Šw‡vxŹz€C 
\end{lstlisting} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `utf8` for `inputenc` and a UTF8 encoded file. You can try using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead (and remove `inputenc`). But if the symbols are obscure enough, you'd have to tell TeX about them and, of course, pick a font which provides them.

Comment: Update. I've added short version of my document.

Comment: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with xelatex or lualatex, provided you load the `fontenc` package. You can't put all those strange characters, however, inside a `lstlisting`.

They are printed fine, for example, in a `verbatim` environment.

MWE (I've reduced the size to `\scriptsize` and increased the width of the page to let it fit in the line)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{verbatim}
Z‰~xŹz€B…z‰~xŹz€A5xŹz‡Ś„Ž5‰„~xŹz€A"V5v5‰Ž‚5‰„~xŹ€Š5… zx~„Ž5€„ŹŽxŹz€A"l5€„ŹŽxŹ€Š5vwČŠŹ€„A5Ś5vwČŠŹ€Š5‡„wvxŹz€A"V5v5‰Ž‚5‡„wvxŹ€Š5Ź~z„Ž5€‌​Šw‡vxŹz€C
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Output (zoomed in)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it work's pretty well for this text, yet some symbols (like hearths, TM, etc) doesn't

Comment: @Tom Happy it helped.

Comment: And is there any way to print any possible character? (the most custom and unusuall ones)

Comment: @Tom Have you tried them outside `verbatim`?